# find the area of the largest rectangle inscribed in a triangle base on x axis

Tags: calculus

I have a rectangle inscribed in a triangle
the triangle having the base on X-axis with the points $(-2,0)$, $(2,0)$ and its head is $(0,6)$.

The challenge is to find the largest area of that rectangle inscribed in this  triangle.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the first quadrant (symmetry):

$y=-3(x-2).$

Area of an inscribed rectangle:

$A=yx =-3(x-2)x$, $x \in [0,2]$

Maximize $A(x)$ by completing the square:

$A(x)= -3x^2+6x= -3(x^2-2x)$;

$A(x)= -3((x-1)^2-1)=-3(x-1)^2+3 \le 3.$

$\max A(x) =A(x=1)$;

Area of rectangle inscribed in original triangle is twice this area:

$A_{Total}= 2×3=6$.

Comment: $+1$, Nice!  No calculus necessary :D

Comment: Kaj Hansen. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

If a rectangle is to be inscribed in this triangle, notice that it must have reflective symmetry over the vertical axis.  Choosing a point $(x, 0)$ along the positive horizontal axis as one of its vertices, the other vertices will be at $(-x, 0)$ and $\Big(\pm x, f(x)\Big)$, where $f$ is the function whose graph is the line connecting $(2, 0)$ and $(0,6)$.

Check that the area of this generic inscribed rectangle is given by $A(x) = 2xf(x)$.  Finally, maximize this function on the interval $0 \leq x \leq 2$ via the usual method of taking a derivative and setting it equal to zero (conveniently, no need to check the endpoints of this interval as such choices for $x$ correspond to [*degenerate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(mathematics)#Rectangle) rectangles of zero area).  As an aside, note that the [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) guarantees that $A$ does indeed attain a maximum on this interval.

I'll leave it to you to fill in the details, but I'm happy to check your work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad writing, but I lost my pen so I had to use the mouse :)

[image]

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.